# Argument of a function

Tags: php

i recently started learning more about PHP and i have a question about arguments, maybe someone can explain it to me better.
I created a function from where it has to take certain variables and if those variables are not global, my script doesnt work as it should.

My function looks like this

```
function adminEditUser() {
        global $connect, $userEditName, $userEditPwd, $userEditFirstN, $userEditLastN, $userEditEmail, $userEditAvatar, $userEditRole, $userEditSts, $userLastEdit;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = $getUserId ";
        $adminEditUser = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        checkQuery($adminEditUser);
        
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($adminEditUser)) {
            $userEditName = $row['username'];
            $userEditPwd = $row['password'];
            $userEditFirstN = $row['firstname'];
            $userEditLastN = $row['lastname'];
            $userEditEmail = $row['email'];
            $userEditAvatar = $row['image'];
            $userEditRole = $row['role'];
            //$userRandSalt = $row['randSalt'];
            $userEditSts = $row['status'];
            $userLastEdit = $row['last_edit'];
        }
[...]
```

I need a little help, how can i change those global variables intro arguments?
Can someone explain to me?

Comment: It seems like you need to learn about return values more than input arguments. Realistically, all you need to pass to the function is the connection. All these other variables are only being assigned to, meaning they make no sense as parameters. Whatever you're using them for, you should use returned values from the function in their place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

function adminEditUser($connect, $userEditName, $userEditPwd, $userEditFirstN, $userEditLastN, $userEditEmail, $userEditAvatar, $userEditRole, $userEditSts, $userLastEdit) {

...

and call it by

adminEditUser($connect, $userEditName, $userEditPwd, $userEditFirstN, $userEditLastN, $userEditEmail, $userEditAvatar, $userEditRole, $userEditSts, $userLastEdit);

PS variable names can be different